# Array of Typed Objects – Extract Union Type of Values for a Given Key

Tags: typescript

I have a constant that holds an array of objects. Here is a simplified version:

```js
interface Config {
  key: string
  url: string
}

const CONFIG_ARR: readonly Config[] = [
  {
    key: 'home',
    url: '/home'
  },
  {
    key: 'product',
    url: '/product'
  }
] as const
```

I want to extract a type `ConfigKey` that is a union of all of the keys. If I remove the `Config` interface, I could do the following:

```js
type ConfigKey = typeof CONFIG_ARR[number]['key']

const CONFIG_ARR = [
  {
    key: 'home',
    url: '/home'
  },
  {
    key: 'product',
    url: '/product'
  }
] as const
```

Is it possible to keep the inferred `ConfigKey` type while preserving the use of the `Config` interface?

Comment: You've widened the type and lost the information via `key: string`. You probably want to say it [_satisfies_](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator) that type.

Comment: I'd say you want [the `satisfies` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator).  See the linked q/a

Comment: `satisfies` https://tsplay.dev/wX1E1N